docker image pull stedolan/jq fails on deprecation
Error seen is:
+++ docker run --rm -i stedolan/jq '.architectures.x86_64.artifacts.qemu.formats["qcow2.gz"].disk.location'
+++ tr -d '"'
Unable to find image 'stedolan/jq:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from stedolan/jq
docker: [DEPRECATION NOTICE] Docker Image Format v1 and Docker Image manifest version 2, schema 1 support is disabled by default and will be removed in an upcoming release. Suggest the author of docker.io/stedolan/jq:latest to upgrade the image to the OCI Format or Docker Image manifest v2, schema 2. More information at https://docs.docker.com/go/deprecated-image-specs/.

See where it fails here.
Can you please bump the Image manifest to v2?
trying to run the dockerized jq, expecting it to work :)

"Can you please bump the Image manifest to v2?" – no we can't, because Stackoverflow is not the maintainer of jq. Best to submit a patch to the project yourself

The latest Docker images of jq can be found in the GitHub container registry:
docker pull ghcr.io/jqlang/jq:1.7.1

It's linked directly from the project's README file.
